# MorganaXProc-IIIse XSLTConnector or XSLTConnector error

Tags: xslt, xproc

I'm using MorganaXProc-IIIse (XPROC 3.0) to execute the following code:

```
<p:declare-step xmlns:p="http://www.w3.org/ns/xproc" version="3.0">
    <p:output port="result"/>
    <p:xslt name="xml-author_list">
        <p:with-input port="source">
            <p:document href="content.xml"/>
        </p:with-input>
        <p:with-input port="stylesheet">
            <p:document href="test.xsl"/>
        </p:with-input>
    </p:xslt>
</p:declare-step>
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
Check your configuration: Cannot initialize XSLTConnector with 'com.xml_project.morganaxproc3.saxon10connector.Saxon10XSLTConnector'.    
<c:errors xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/ns/xproc-step">
       <c:error code="err:XC0038"
                name="xml-author_list"
                type="p:xslt"
                href="file:///Users/bob/Dev/Workspace/IdeaProjects/test/test/test.xpl"
                line="4"
                column="36"
                xmlns:p="http://www.w3.org/ns/xproc"
                xmlns:err="http://www.w3.org/ns/xproc-error">
          <message>Requested XSLT version '3.0' is not supported by choosen XSLTConnector or XSLTConnector configuration error.</message>
       </c:error>
    </c:errors>
```

So I tried change the XSLTConnector to Saxon10. The Saxon10Connector is already in the lib directory of Morgana. Here is my config.xml:

```
<morgana-config xmlns="http://www.xml-project.com/morganaxproc">
    <path_to_iso_skeleton_schematron_1>ISO_SKELETON_SCHEMATRON_1</path_to_iso_skeleton_schematron_1>
    <path_to_iso_skeleton_schematron_2>ISO_SKELETON_SCHEMATRON_2</path_to_iso_skeleton_schematron_2>
    <path_to_SchXSLT_1>schxslt-1.4.5-sources/xslt/1.0</path_to_SchXSLT_1>
    <path_to_SchXSLT_2>schxslt-1.4.5-sources/xslt/2.0</path_to_SchXSLT_2>
    <XSLTValidationMode>STRICT</XSLTValidationMode>
    <xslt-connector>Saxon10</xslt-connector>
</morgana-config>
```

And then I execute:

```
sh Morgana.sh /Users/bob/Dev/Workspace/IdeaProjects/test/test/test.xpl -xslt-connector=saxon10 -xquery-connector=saxon10 -indent-errors -debug
```

But the error still occurs. I cannot find any information about which XSLTConnector supports XSL-Stylesheet Version 3.0

Any hint is highly appreciated.

Comment: Drop the SaxonHE10-6.jar (from Sourceforge) into the libraries folder of Morgana.

Comment: See also https://www.xml-project.com/files/doc/manual.html#d5e121.

Comment: I dropped saxon-he-10.6.jar into the lib folder of Morgana, but I still get the error: Check your configuration: Cannot initialize XSLTConnector with 'com.xml_project.morganaxproc3.saxon10connector.Saxon10XSLTConnector'.

Comment: Which release of Morgana exactly is that?

Comment: I used MorganaXProc-IIIse 0.9.6.1-beta

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [documentation](https://www.xml-project.com/files/doc/manual.html#d5e121) it says:

> The current search order for a Saxon implementation is saxon9ee.jar,
> saxon9pe.jar, saxon9he.jar, saxon-ee-10.0.jar, saxon-pe-10.0.jar,
> saxon-he-10.0.jar, saxon-ee-10.1.jar, saxon-pe-10.1.jar and
> saxon-he-10.1.jar. MorganaXProc-IIIse will use the first Saxon version
> found by this search order.

But since the recommended Saxon Version for Saxon 10 is Saxon 10.3:

> Recommened to be used with Saxon 10.3

one can assume that it will work with 10.3 as well as with any new release.

However, with 10.3 and 10.6 I still got the same error. I assumed maybe there is a Saxon 9.x Version in the lib folder and therefore selecting the wrong version due to the search order. But that wasn't the case.

When I added 10.0 like mentioned in the search order, it works.

Comment: Perhaps ask Achim in a ticket on the Morgana Sourceforge site https://sourceforge.net/p/morganaxproc-iiise/tickets/ whether using Saxon HE 10.6 is supported and if so, how. The changes files for the latest release says "Checked with SaxonHE 10.6" so that sounds as if Saxon HE 10.6 should work.

Comment: Thank you. Added a ticket here https://sourceforge.net/p/morganaxproc-iiise/tickets/73/